# If $X = (X_1, X_2, \dots, X_d)$ has density $p_X$, what is the density of $X_1 + X_2$? (Le Gall, 8.6)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, analysis, probability-distributions

**Exercise 8.6**

> Let $X = (X_1, X_2, \dots, X_d)$ be a random vector with values in $\mathbb R^d$. Assume that the law of $X$ has a density $p_X(x_1, \dots, x_d)$. Compute the density of the random variable $X_1 + X_2$ in terms of the function $p_X$.

I've looked for related questions, but everything I've found makes additional assumptions like independence and/or a specific form of the density, so I haven't found anything applicable.

**My attempt:**

I'm really out of my depth with this question. The map $(X_1, X_2, \dots, X_d) \mapsto X_1 + X_2$ is obviously not a diffeomorphism, so change of variables doesn't apply. Convolutions are relevant only for sums of independent random variables.

I know that the density of $X_1$ can be found by integrating $p_X$ over all $\mathrm d x_2 \dots \mathrm d x_d$ but I don't see how that helps me find the density of $X_1 + X_2$.

I appreciate any help in how to go about this.

Comment: $$P[X_1+X_1\leq z]=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-2}}\Big(\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int^{z-x_2}_{-\infty} \Big(p(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\,dx_1\Big) dx_2\Big)\ldots dx_n$$

Comment: @Mittens Thanks. So the idea is to differentiate $P[X_1 + X_2 \leq z]$, then?

Comment: Yes, but some additional manipulations (using Fubini's theorem) are needed to perform a clean differentiation. See my posting for additional details ( I leave some details you).

Comment: You can also use the denisty transformation formula with $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_d)\mapsto(x_1+x_2,x_2,\ldots,x_d)$...

Answer (score 1):

> I know that the density of $X_1$ can be found by integrating $p_X$ over all $\mathrm d x_2 \dots \mathrm d x_d$ but I don't see how that helps me find the density of $X_1 + X_2$.

The *joint* density function of $X_1$ and $X_2$ may be found by integrating over one less variable.

$$p_{\small X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)=\iiint_{\Bbb R^{d-2}}p_{\small X}(x_1,x_2,s_3,...,s_d)\,\mathrm d s_d\ldots\mathrm d s_3$$

Once you have that, change of variables can apply.  $(X_1,X_2)\mapsto(X_1,X_1+X_2)$

> Convolutions are relevant only for sums of independent random variables.

No, the variables do not need to be independent; convolution *will* work with a joint probability density function.

$$p_{\small X_1+X_2}(z) = \int_\Bbb R p_{\small X_1,X_2}(z-t,t)\,\mathrm d t$$

Answer (score 1):

The joint distribution of $X_1$ and $X_2$ is gas a destiny with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by
$$f(x_1,x_2)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-2}}p(x_1,x_2,\mathbf{x})\,d\mathbf{x}$$

Now, for any $z\in\mathbb{R}$
\begin{align}
P[X_1+X_2\leq z]&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\Big(\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,z]}(x_1+x_2)f(x_1,x_2)dx_2\Big)dx_1\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\Big(\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,z]}(x_2)f(x_1,x_2-x_1)\,dx_2\Big)\,dx_1\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,z]}(x_2)\Big(\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x_1,x_2-x_1)\,dx_1\Big)dx_2\\
\end{align}

Alternatively

\begin{align}
P[X_1+X_2\leq z]&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\Big(\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,z]}(x_1+x_2)f(x_1,x_2)dx_1\Big)dx_2\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\Big(\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,z]}(x_1)f(x_1-x_2,x_2)\,dx_1\Big)\,dx_2\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,z]}(x_1)\Big(\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x_1-x_2,x_2)\,dx_2\Big)dx_1\\
\end{align}

Can you finish from here?

You should get
$$g(z)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x_1,z-x_1)\,dx_1=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(z-x_2,x_2)\,dx_2$$

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think my calculus/analysis is a bit too weak to see the solution, so I am going to try with the change of variables from the other answer, and then maybe think about this later. Thanks again.

Comment: I@caitlin: t is mostly about changing order of integration and also using the fact that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(t)\,dt=\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(t-a)dt$ for all $a$ and for all integral function $g$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\A}{\mathcal{A}}
\newcommand{\Pset}{\mathcal{P}}
\newcommand{\Prob}{\mathbb{P}}
\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
\newcommand{\diff}{\, \mathrm d}
$$

Here is a (perhaps painfully pedantic and obvious) derivation of the change-of-variables approach, as suggested by Graham Kemp.

First, as in Proposition 8.6 in the Le Gall textbook, we argue that the density of $(X_1, X_2)$ is given by

$$
    p_{X_1, X_2}(x_1, x_2) = \int_{\R^{d - 2}} p_X(x_1, \dots, x_d) \diff x_3 \dots \diff x_d.
$$

Let $\pi_{1, 2} \colon \R^d \to \R^2$ be the projection onto the first two coordinates. Following the proposition, for any Borel function $f \colon \R^2 \to \R$,

\begin{align*}
    \E\left[f(X_1, X_2)\right] &= \E\left[f\left(\pi_{1, 2}(X)\right)\right]\\
    &= \int_{\R^d} f(x_1, x_2) p_X(x_1, \dots, x_d) \diff x_1 \dots \diff x_d\\
    &= \int_{\R^2} f(x_1, x_2) \left( \int_{\R^{d - 2}} p_X(x_1, \dots, x_d) \diff x_3 \dots \diff x_d\right) \diff x_1 \diff x_2\\
    &= \int_{\R^2} f(x_1, x_2) p_{X_1, X_2}(x_1, x_2) \diff x_1 \diff x_2.
\end{align*}

Next, we consider the diffeomorphism $\varphi \colon \R^2 \to \R^2$ given by $\varphi(x_1, x_2) = (x_1, x_1 + x_2)$. By the change of variables formula, the density of $\varphi(X_1, X_2) := (Y_1, Y_2)$ is given by

$$
    p_{Y_1, Y_2}(y_1, y_2) = p_{X_1, X_2}\left(\varphi^{-1}(y_1, y_2)\right)\left\lvert \text{det } J_{\varphi^{-1}} \big\lvert_{(y_1, y_2)} \right\rvert,
$$

where $J_{\varphi^{-1}}$ is the Jacobian of the inverse map $\varphi^{-1} \colon \R^2 \to \R^2$. Specifically, we have

\begin{align*}
    \varphi^{-1}(y_1, y_2) &= \left(\varphi_1^{-1}(y_1, y_2), \varphi_2^{-1}(y_1, y_2)\right)\\
    &= (y_1, y_2 - y_1).
\end{align*}

Therefore

\begin{align*}
    J_{\varphi^{-1}} &=
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \frac{\partial \varphi_1^{-1}}{\partial y_1} & \frac{\partial \varphi_1^{-1}}{\partial y_2}\\
        \frac{\partial \varphi_2^{-1}}{\partial y_1} & \frac{\partial \varphi_2^{-1}}{\partial y_2}
    \end{pmatrix}\\
    &=
    \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0\\
        -1 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}\\
    \implies \text{det } J_{\varphi^{-1}} &= 1.
\end{align*}

Therefore, the density of $(X_1, X_1 + X_2)$ is

$$
    p_{X_1, X_1 + X_2}(y_1, y_2) = p_{X_1, X_2}(y_1, y_2 - y_1),
$$

and therefore we can integrate out the first variable to see that

$$
    p_{X_1 + X_2}(y_2) = \int_{\R} p_{X_1, X_2}(y_1, y_2 - y_1) \diff y_1.
$$